# How to eliminate restrictions of full-text for the number of results?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

According to my researches, I figured out *(in full-text search)* if the difference between the total number of rows and number of results be less or equal than the number of results, then result will be zero *(or not found anything)*.

Here is an **example**, please Take a look at this:

```
// table - The number of total rows: 3
+----+-------+
| id |  col  |
+----+-------+
| 1  |  one  |
| 2  |  one  |
| 3  |  two  |
+----+-------+
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`col`) AGAINST ('one');
```

**Result:** [There is 0 result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbed6/1). (Why? I think Because the number of results is `2`, also the number of total rows is `3`, So `3 - 2 = 1`, and `2 > 1`, Then the result will be `0`.)

---

Now I want to know, how can I remove this limitation? In other word, I want when I search `one`, the result be this:

```
+----+-------+
| 1  |  one  |
| 2  |  one  |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Try updating the values one as 'xxxx' and two as 'yyyy'. test the query with the updated values. If it is a live table try with a temp table. I had the same  result ? what is the max length characters in that field...

Comment: "one" is in the [list of stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). The index ignores it completely.

Comment: @chandran I did it, still there is no result. *(@Vate I changed `one` and `two` values. But there is not any difference.)*

Comment: i kept one value as 'chan' and another as 'sun' only chan rows listed.. then i changed to 'sunn' .. then it listed me both value rows

Comment: mysql> select id,col from test where match(`col`) against ('subh');select id,col from test where match(col) against ('chan');
+----+------+
| id | col  |
+----+------+
| 11 | subh |
| 12 | subh |
| 13 | subh |
| 14 | subh |
| 15 | subh |
+----+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------+
| id | col  |
+----+------+
|  2 | chan |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @chandran please give me a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query show your ft_min_word_len field value and it should be 3 if it is 4 then might not work with length of 3 characters.

> mysql> show variables like '%len';
>
> ft_min_word_len      | 3     |

change that in my.cnf 
add below in mysqld block

> ft_min_word_len = 3

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71583a/2

try adding IN BOLLEAN MODE in the search pattern as below

> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`col`) AGAINST ('one'  IN BOOLEAN
>   MODE); SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`col`) AGAINST ('two'  IN
>   BOOLEAN MODE);

fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71583a/2

Comment: Yes ...! Using `in boolean mode` is my answer.